# `capture_tpu_profile` not able to access the TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tpu

I have the following TPU:

```
$ gcloud compute tpus list 
NAME         ZONE           ACCELERATOR_TYPE  NETWORK_ENDPOINTS  NETWORK  RANGE          STATUS
daniels-tpu  us-central1-a  v3-8              10.240.1.10:8470   default  10.240.1.8/29  READY
```

But it is not accessible via `capture_tpu_profile`:

```
$  capture_tpu_profile --tpu=daniels-tpu 
TensorFlow version 1.15.2 detected
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

W0131 10:15:16.553251 4571966912 lazy_loader.py:50] 
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 938, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/capture_tpu_profile", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cloud_tpu_profiler/main.py", line 85, in run_main
    tf.compat.v1.app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cloud_tpu_profiler/main.py", line 105, in main
    [FLAGS.tpu], zone=FLAGS.tpu_zone, project=FLAGS.gcp_project))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/tpu_cluster_resolver.py", line 330, in __init__
    self._request_compute_metadata('project/project-id'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/tpu_cluster_resolver.py", line 124, in _request_compute_metadata
    resp = urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1347, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1321, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

The error didn't go away even after using `--tpu_zone=us-central1-a` flag.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `capture_tpu_profile` to capture a profile, a .tracetable file is saved to your Google Cloud Storage bucket, if this location is not provided, then it will go nowhere.

Can you try adding the path of you bucket with the following command:

```
capture_tpu_profile --tpu=tpu-name --logdir=${MODEL_DIR}
```

--logdir=${MODEL_DIR} - This is a Cloud Storage location where your model and checkpoints are stored.

All details mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorboard-setup)