# capture_tpu_profile failed to connect to all address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, tpu

I'm trying to run the command from [Cloud TPU Tools to monitor job](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools#monitor_job).

```
capture_tpu_profile --tpu=[my-tpu-name] --monitoring_level=2 --tpu_zone=[my-tpu-zone]
```

It yields the following error

```
    2022-08-07 08:42:22.253271: I tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_initializer_helper.cc:66] libtpu.so already in used by another process. Not attempting to load libtpu.so in this process.
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogle() is written to STDERR
I0807 08:42:22.273403  426417 tpu_initializer_helper.cc:66] libtpu.so already in used by another process. Not attempting to load libtpu.so in this process.
2022-08-07 08:42:22.287995: I tensorflow/core/tpu/tpu_initializer_helper.cc:66] libtpu.so already in used by another process. Not attempting to load libtpu.so in this process.
TensorFlow version 2.6.0 detected
Welcome to the Cloud TPU Profiler v2.4.0
I0807 08:42:23.432723 140287849856064 discovery.py:280] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tpu/v1/rest
I0807 08:42:23.574428 140287849856064 discovery.py:911] URL being requested: GET https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[admin name]/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/[my tpu name]?alt=json
I0807 08:42:23.574645 140287849856064 transport.py:157] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
I0807 08:42:23.626410 140287849856064 discovery.py:280] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tpu/v1/rest
I0807 08:42:24.250050 140287849856064 discovery.py:911] URL being requested: GET https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[admin name]/locations/europe-west4-a/nodes/[my tpu name]?alt=json
I0807 08:42:24.250258 140287849856064 transport.py:157] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
Since monitoring level is provided, profile 10.164.0.16:8466  for  0  ms and show metrics for  100  time(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[my name]/.local/bin/capture_tpu_profile", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/home/[my name]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloud_tpu_profiler/capture_tpu_profile.py", line 136, in run_main
    app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/[my name]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloud_tpu_profiler/capture_tpu_profile.py", line 184, in main
    monitoring_helper(service_addr, duration_ms, FLAGS.monitoring_level,
  File "/home/[my name]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloud_tpu_profiler/capture_tpu_profile.py", line 131, in monitoring_helper
    res = profiler_client.monitor(service_addr, duration_ms, monitoring_level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/profiler_client.py", line 167, in monitor
    return _pywrap_profiler.monitor(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnavailableError: failed to connect to all addresses
```

I have looked some similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009383/capture-tpu-profile-not-able-to-access-the-tpu), but the error is quite different. How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [TPU VM architecture](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture-tpu-vm#tpu-arch) details in [TPU VMs quick start](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quick-starts#cloud-tpu-quickstarts)

`capture_tpu_profile` is not supported for TPU VM (only supported for TPU Node architecture). For TPU VM profiling please follow:

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/profile-tpu-vm